# Making Date in SQL between two dates

Tags: sql, db-browser-sqlite

I'm working in DB Browser for SQLite, and have written a query:

```
SELECT "Trade Details 2".TRADE_TYPOLOGY,
        "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID,
        DATE("Trade Details 2".START_DATE) as START_DATE,
        DATE(substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 0, 5) || '-' || 
        substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 5,2) || '-' ||   
        substr("Trade Details 
        2".MATURITY_DATE, 7, 9)) as MATURITY_DATE,
        "Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1,
        "Trade Details 2".COUNTERPARTYNAME,
        "Trade Details".TERM
        FROM "Trade Details 2"
        JOIN "Trade Details"
        WHERE "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID="Trade Details".FC_ID
        ORDER BY "Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE desc
```

My goal is to quantity the MATURITY_DATE, so that when I run my SQL query I only get trades with MATURITY_DATE between 2018-06-22 and 2099-12-30. However, I'm not exactly sure what line to add in in order to achieve this goal. However, when I added the line

```
2099-12-30>"Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE>2018-06-22
```

above my order by statement and below my where statement, I got no output when I ran it. How would I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to use `AND` with `BETWEEN` in `where` caluse.

```
SELECT "Trade Details 2".TRADE_TYPOLOGY,
        "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID,
        DATE("Trade Details 2".START_DATE) as START_DATE,
        DATE(substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 0, 5) || '-' || 
        substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 5,2) || '-' ||   
        substr("Trade Details 
        2".MATURITY_DATE, 7, 9)) as MATURITY_DATE,
        "Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1,
        "Trade Details 2".COUNTERPARTYNAME,
        "Trade Details".TERM
        FROM "Trade Details 2"
        JOIN "Trade Details"
WHERE 
   "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID="Trade Details".FC_ID
AND 
   "Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE BETWEEN '2018-06-22' AND '2099-12-30'
ORDER BY "Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE desc
```

or Use greater than and less than

```
SELECT "Trade Details 2".TRADE_TYPOLOGY,
        "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID,
        DATE("Trade Details 2".START_DATE) as START_DATE,
        DATE(substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 0, 5) || '-' || 
        substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 5,2) || '-' ||   
        substr("Trade Details 
        2".MATURITY_DATE, 7, 9)) as MATURITY_DATE,
        "Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1,
        "Trade Details 2".COUNTERPARTYNAME,
        "Trade Details".TERM
        FROM "Trade Details 2"
        JOIN "Trade Details"
WHERE 
   "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID="Trade Details".FC_ID
AND 
   "Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE > '2018-06-22' AND   "Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE < '2099-12-30'
ORDER BY "Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE desc
```